# Hive unit testing on windows without hadoop setup

Tags: hadoop, junit, hive, mrunit

I am looking to see if there is a way to run Hive unit tests (i.e unit testing the hive queries) in Windows without having a hadoop/hive/cygwin setup.  Came across these open source tools (Hive_runner, HiveTest),  tried running hiverunner in Eclipse as maven project, its JUnit tests failed with the following warning and error

Warning: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform....using built-in java classes where applicable.
 Error: Failed to set permission of path ? to 0700

Thanks
Srivatsan Nallazhagappan

Answer (score 1):

The HiveQLUnit open source project solves your problem of executing standalone unit tests from your favorite IDE. Check it out @[HiveQLUnit](http://finraos.github.io/HiveQLUnit/)

It can execute unit tests from your favorite IDE on any operating system including Windows, Linux and Mac OSX. Here is some guidance around running it from your IDE - [Running HiveQLUnit](https://github.com/FINRAOS/HiveQLUnit/blob/master/userguides/RunningHiveQLUnitTests.md)

Note: I am affiliated with the HiveQLUnit OS project.